# How to create a main_category attribute for a product?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, category-products

I want to create a second category assignment for my products which is limited to one category. The select should be similar to the default category assignment.

What I want is setting a main-category for each product which is used for tagging a product in diverse feeds.

I have absolutely no idea how to realize this and it would be great to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: You have to Create InstallData.php**

Create file InstallData.php

We will start with the InstallData class which located in app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php. The content for this file:

```
<?php
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

}
```

**Step 2:  Define the install() method**

```
<?php

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

}
```

**Step 3: Create the category attribute**

```
?php
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'mp_new_attribute',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Custom Attribute',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => 1,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
            );
    }
}
```

**Step 4: Display the category attribute**

The category UI Component is rendered with configuration from the category_form.xml file. All files with that name are merged together. As a result, We will add a field by creating a category_form.xml file in the app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="mp_new_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Custom Main Attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

All done, please run upgrade, flush cache and check the result.

```
**Flush Cache Run flush cache here**

**Run upgrade command line:**
```

Then go to **Product > Categories** from the admin to check the result.

This type you can easily create main_category attribute for a product.

Comment: Hello Harshad, thank you for your basic product attribute kind of text. But unfortunately it's just a textfield and not based on the actual categories in my store. I want to have a select like the default category assignment.

Comment: There is a simple solution which Magento 2.x provides by default.

    Go to Products > Categories.
    Click on the (parent) category in which you want to show the products of the sub-category.
    Under Display Settings, set Yes for Anchor field.
    Save the category, flush Magento's cache and reindex.

Please let me know if the solution works for you.

Comment: Harshad... no. This is not what I wanted. Please read my question. I want to set one specific main category for my product. I want to select the main category by a select similiar to the default magento ones.